# SQL Join and Update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So I want to update the action column to the value 'Insert' inside Table1, if the ids from Table1 and Table2 match but the UIDs dont.

Right now my query looks like

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Action = 'Insert'
FROM Table1
    JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id
        AND Table1.UID <> Table2.UID
```

This is setting the action to Insert even if the UIDs *don't* differ, can someone help me and explain why this is behaving this way?

Comment: what is happening when you do "inner join"

Comment: Add sample data please.

Comment: @AaronDietz im so sorry I meant even if the UIDs dont differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is you have something like this:

```
Table1
id   |  UID  |  action
1    |   1   |   bla
1    |   2   |   bleck
1    |   3   |   floop

Table2
id   |  UID  |  action
1    |   1   |   bla
1    |   2   |   bleck
1    |   4   |   floop
```

And you hope to update the third row in `Table1` because the `UID` isn't in `Table2`.

The problem is that the third row in `Table2` matches all rows in `Table1` on your condition: `Table1.id = Table2.id AND Table1.UID <> Table2.UID`

Which means that in this case, all rows in `Table1` will be updated with `Action = 'Insert'`

I think you want to use `NOT EXISTS()`:

```
UPDATE T1
SET Action = 'Insert'
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM Table2 T2
                  WHERE T1.id = T2.id
                  AND T1.UID = T2.UID)
```

**Edit, more explanation on why the join fails:**

This is a many to many join, meaning that the condition allows multiple rows from `Table1` to match multiple rows from `Table2`

The easiest way to see this in action is to change your update to a select:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 on T1.id = T2.id
              and T1.UID <> T2.UID
```

You may expect this to result in:

```
id   |  UID  |  action     id   |  UID  |  action
1    |   3   |   floop     1    |   4   |   floop
```

But really it will result in:

```
id   |  UID  |  action     id   |  UID  |  action
1    |   1   |   bla       1    |   4   |   floop
1    |   2   |   bleck     1    |   4   |   floop
1    |   3   |   floop     1    |   4   |   floop
```

This means that when you update you are hitting all the rows for `id = 1` in `Table1`

Comment: Thank you so much, the solution worked. Although I'm still a little confused as to why all the rows will update, I thought the join combined and rows where the conditions for each row meet? Why would it change all of them just because one row matches from the other table matches?

Comment: @JoeViscardi NP, I added some further explanation to the answer.  Your best bet is to run a select and look at the results - see how the `table1` rows are lining up with the `table2` rows, that should clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you put condition Table1.UID <> Table2.UID into WHERE clause, doesn't it solve your problem?

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Action = 'Insert'
FROM Table1
    JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id
WHERE Table1.UID <> Table2.UID
```